# Find last match of a string only using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use powershell to look through a log file for a particular string, and only return the last instance of it into a variable for later use.

Example of the log:

```
09/07/17 13:27:19.858 TCP/IP Terminal.GetVersionInfo AppVersion         [RA 4.0.560]
09/07/17 13:27:19.858 TCP/IP Terminal.GetVersionInfo OSVersion          [L5x-OS-v00.00-20170000-0]
09/07/17 13:27:19.858 TCP/IP Terminal.GetVersionInfo PackingListVersion [0001]
09/07/17 13:27:19.858 TCP/IP Terminal.GetVersionInfo TerminalName       [LXXXX_PCI3]
09/07/17 16:28:17.300 TCP/IP Terminal.GetVersionInfo AppVersion         [RA 4.0.561]
```

Just the last result of AppVersion is what I want to return:

[RA 4.0.561]

**EDIT:**

I've tried to loop through each line and put the results in an array but the array is giving me strange results:

```
$results = @()
foreach ($line in $logfile) {
    $hits = [regex]::match($line,'\[RA.\d.*]')
    $results += $hits.Value
}
$results
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[LotPings' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46125917/45375) is promising, but there's a simpler way to do it, without the need for an aux. variable:

```
Select-String ' AppVersion\s+(\[.+?\])' $logfile | 
  Select-Object -Last 1 |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value }
```

Given that by definition there will be at most 1 match, we could also do:

```
(Select-String ' AppVersion\s+(\[.+?\])' $logfile | Select-Object -Last 1).
  Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
```

If collecting all matches in memory first before selecting the last one is feasible:

```
(Select-String ' AppVersion\s+(\[.+?\])' $logfile)[-1].Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select-String -Path $logfile -Pattern 'AppVersion\s+(\[.+\])' -Allmatches|
    ForEach-Object{$Result=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
$Result
```

Sample output:

```
[RA 4.0.561]
```

Comment: Promising, but `-AllMatches` is only needed for multiple matches _per line_.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along the lines of the following to split the text into single items and search in reverse order?

```
$rawStr = cat $logfile //read logfile to variable
$list = $rawStr.split("`n") //split text at newlines
[array]::Reverse($list) //reverse list
$list | % {if ($_ -match "AppVersion") { echo $_; break } }
```

Comment: `Get-Content` reads a file in as an array of strings by default, you don't need to split on new lines. A more elegant way to do your last line would be `$list | Where{$_ -match 'AppVersion\s+(\[.*])'} | ForEach{$Matches[1]; break}` That should just return `[RA 4.0.561]`.

Comment: Working on a mac so I wasn't able to test that first part -- thanks for clarifying. That is much cleaner, there are so many ways to do things in PowerShell. Very cool, cheers.